'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
When I am trying to run my Vue js project its raising error like , 'Vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Please help me to solve this error.
I have done all the required set up for this like env path set up done , I installed Vue-cli its also working if I am creating another project so that is working fine but the problem is in that project which I have cloned pleas help me to resolve this issue.

vue --version
@vue/cli 5.0.8

Search this site for the exact phrase not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. This question has been asked and answered literally hundreds of times here already, and I'm quite certain that at least one of them will be of help to you to solve the problem.

provide steps to reproduce the problem

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . vue-cli-service is supposed to be local dependency of the project, it's not related to global vue cli. That there's none suggests it's missing in the deps or they were incorrectly installed
